# Looping through Arrays - better way?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to arrays but there has to be a better way to loop through arrays than what I am doing. This code is ugly. Please let me know of any ideas. The idea for this program is when a user enters what size shirt they need and they will receive a discount based on the quantity. If more than 2 (they receive 10% discount, if >=3 and <= 4 they receive 15% discount, if >= 5 they receive 25% discount .

Here is my code:

```
string userInputString;
string userInput;
int userInputNo= 0;
double userPrice = 0;
string userSize = "";
string[,] prices = {{"S", "5.00"}, {"M", "7.00"}, {"L", "9.00"}, {"X", "12.00"} };

Console.Write("What size shirt (S, M, L, OR X-Large): ");

userInputString = Console.ReadLine();
userInput = Convert.ToString(userInputString);
Console.Write("How many shirts do you need?: ");
userInputString = Console.ReadLine();
userInputNo = Convert.ToInt32(userInputString);

if (userInputNo == 2)
{
    if (userInput == prices[0,0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[0,1]) * 0.10) +  Convert.ToDouble(prices[0,1]));
        userSize = prices[0,0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[1, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]) * 0.10) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]));
        userSize = prices[1, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[2, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]) * 0.10) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]));
        userSize = prices[2, 0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]) * 0.10) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]));
        userSize = prices[3, 0].ToString();
    }
}
else if (userInputNo >= 3 && userInputNo <= 4)
{
    if (userInput == prices[0, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[0, 1]) * 0.15) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[0, 1]));
        userSize = prices[0, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[1, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]) * 0.15) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]));
        userSize = prices[1, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[2, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]) * 0.15) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]));
        userSize = prices[2, 0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]) * 0.15) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]));
        userSize = prices[3, 0].ToString();
    }
}
else if (userInputNo >= 5)
{
    if (userInput == prices[0, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[0, 1]) * 0.20) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[0, 1]));
        userSize = prices[0, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[1, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]) * 0.20) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[1, 1]));
        userSize = prices[1, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[2, 0])
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]) * 0.20) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[2, 1]));
        userSize = prices[2, 0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        userPrice = ((Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]) * 0.20) + Convert.ToDouble(prices[3, 1]));
        userSize = prices[3, 0].ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    if (userInput == prices[0, 0])
    {
        userPrice = Convert.ToDouble(prices[0,1]);
        userSize = prices[0, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[1, 0])
    {
        userPrice = Convert.ToDouble(prices[1,1]);
        userSize = prices[1, 0].ToString();
    }
    else if (userInput == prices[2, 0])
    {
        userPrice = Convert.ToDouble(prices[2,1]);
        userSize = prices[2, 0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        userPrice = Convert.ToDouble(prices[3,1]);
        userSize = prices[3, 0].ToString();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("For a size {0}, you will pay $ {1}.", userSize.ToString(), userPrice);
```

Comment: You can create an array with discounts find a matching discount with LINQ

Comment: The stated problem is to determine discounts on shirts.  The code as written, prompts the user for pizzas.  There's your first problem. :)

Comment: I do not know how long you have been developing.. but if you are REALLY interested in good ways of writing code, this is when you should look at design patterns... If you are interested i could find some good examples for you... :)

Answer (score 3):

There are no loops in your code.  However, you want a lookup table, not an array, so use `Dictionary<K,V>`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double> {
    {"S", 0.05},
    {"M", 0.07}, 
    {"L", 0.09}, 
    {"X", 0.12}
};
```

And then...

```
userInputString = Console.ReadLine();
var discount = 0.0;
if (dict.TryGetValue(userInputString, out discount))
{
    // discount now holds the discount amount.
    // multiply to get the effective price
}
else
{
    // bad input, alert user
}

// side note: TryGetValue is a method which allows you to
// both test if a key exists and get the value at the same
// time.  if you know that a dictionary contains the key
// you need you can just index into it, i.e.,
// var discount = dict[userInputString];
```

if you are forced to use an array by your homework instructions, then the loop would look like this:

```
var discount = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < prices.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    if (String.Equals(prices[i, 0], userInputString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        discount = prices[i, 0];            
        break;  // found it, all done
    }
}
```

However, this is the wrong route to take.  No need for an O(n) lookup here.

Additionally, don't store everything as a string just to convert it back to a number.  You're writing your code backwards; think in terms of data when writing code and *then* format for output.